# Got manifest errors but it's working well. how to solve this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I've got this anonymous errors. but I don't understand why this occur and how to solve this. when I run my app, it's working well. but I wanna solve this errors. is there any one can help me? I think there is no problem in grammar.

[image]

Comment: It happens sometimes.
Go to Build> Clean Project
Then Build>Rebuild Project.

Comment: invalidate caches and Restart Android Studio

Comment: thanks bro. it solved automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this **File->Invalid Crashes/Restart** or **Build->Clean project**